# Getting Access Forbidden in IIS

Tags: permission-denied

I Have hosted a website in IIS 7.5.Which was working fine till yesterday.But suddenly today am not able to access any of its pages and am getting following error.

**Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403**

Googled a lot but could not find any resolutions.Any Comments will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if anything has changed for the user IIS_IUSRS?

Check what type of security you have in place. Was it anonymous before and needs some type of windows integration?

Comment: Hi jdross,Thank you for quick response.Can you please help me out in checking the same.I.e. what settings should i do for IIS_IUSRS and where should i do the same.

Comment: 1) enabled directory browsing on the virtual folder of the web site, on both the virtual folder where .exe & .asp pages are located.
2) Verified NTFS & IIS permissions, on both the place where .exe & .asp pages are located.
3) On IIS front tried with anonymous access & also provided with the integrated windows authentication, on both the virtual folder where .exe & .asp pages are located

Comment: To grant read, write, and modify permissions to a specific file

In Windows Explorer, locate and select the required file.
Right-click the file, and then click Properties.
In the Properties dialog box, click the Security tab.
On the Security tab, examine the list of users. If the Network Service
account is not listed, add it.
In the Properties dialog box, click the Network Service user name, and in the Permissions for NETWORK SERVICE section, select the Read, Write, and Modify permissions.
Click Apply, and then click OK.